# How can I complete the tutorial install linuxbrew on linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to install [linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/) on my debian OS.

There is something I don't understand.

In part, "Add to your .bashrc or .zshrc", how I'm gonna do it? What is file .bashrc, .zshrc?

Even I type in `cd .linuxbrew` (it is a folder)
`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/blueberry/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >>~/.bash_profile`
 The file doesn't appear in folder( blueberry is my sudo username on OS ).  Is it a hidden file? I even can't edit it.

Here what I've done: [image]

In that 3 line : I have edited. I don't know this is right or not. Why I can't done success? Can somebody explain what I do wrong? This is about that .bashrc, PATH problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, .bash_profile is a hidden file normally found in your HOME directory. Your echo command should work correctly with only one exception. You need to make sure that there is a space between the second ">" and the "~" like this:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/blueberry/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

FYI any file that starts with a dot is a hidden file. To see them from your terminal try:

```
ls -a
```

Meaning "list ALL"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bashBedlam's answer, you should note that the HOME variable in most case has the value /home/, so in your case $HOME/blueberry translate to /home/blueberry/blueberry, which is wrong. Correct command is:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

You can also edit .bash_profile or .bashrc yourself with any editor